# Selecting an option only Display Id not Name in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-forms

I am working on Angular 4 Web API Here  when selecting an option it will display packingtypename its working fine. but my problem is when clicking add button it will only save the packingtypeID i want Packing type id and packing type name Here i want to like this when selecting a PackingTypeName automatically pass their ID to API. which means when selecting a packing type Name and press add button the selected Name and its ID can be saved to DB. actually, I am new in angular. can anyone help please its a big help form me

my Html code is

```
  <label>Packing Type</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="PackingtypeName" placeholder="name" name="PackingtypeName" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" *ngIf="products">
   <option value="0" disabled>Please Select Packing type </option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of products" id={{item.PackingTypeID}} value={{item.PackingTypeID}}>{{item.PackingtypeName}}</option>
 </select>


<input type="button" value="Add Item"[disabled]="!itemdetails"  class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItems(newStockoutForm.value);newStockoutForm.reset()" />
```

my TS file

```
  addItems(value: any) {
 this.items = new IComboDetails(this.PackingTypeID, value.PackingtypeName, );

    console.log(this.PackingTypeID);
    alert(this.PackingTypeID);
    alert(value.PackingtypeName);// here show alert is PackingTypeID 
}

   onSelect(PackingTypeID: number) {
    alert(PackingTypeID);
    this._loginService.selectedpackingtypeid = PackingTypeID;
    this.PackingTypeID = PackingTypeID
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new variable in ts files name - `PackingItem = {};`

in html file change `value={{item.PackingTypeID}}` to `[value]="item"`

then in `addItem()` method check `console.log(this.PackingItem);`

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: add `ngModel` in select 
`<select class="form-control" id="PackingtypeName" placeholder="name" name="PackingtypeName" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selecteItem">`

Then in `addItem()` you can pass this value like this `addItems(selecteItem)`

please check given url and check values in console. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6ydv4

Comment: will check and in form

Comment: That is because you didn't select any value yet, first select any value. Currently default option is disabled.

Comment: what is the issue then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197595/discussion-between-brock-james-and-piyush-jain).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in the value for your option is what you will get on select.

Right now, you're setting it to just the ID, but you can set the value to the whole object if you want.

```
<option *ngFor="let item of products" id="{{item.PackingTypeID}}" [value]="item">{{item.PackingtypeName}}</option>
```

This will give you the whole item to play with on select instead of a single value.

Your onSelect will now look like:

```
onSelect(item: PackingType) {
  alert(`ID: ${item.PackingTypeID} - Name: ${item.PackingtypeName}`);
}
```

(Assuming your DTO is a `PackingType` type - I don't see any reference to the exact type you're using.. but I guess `any` would do. Either way, the object will be the actual item object).

Edit: added full option line, including mentioned fix for [input] of the value, and example of updated onSelect method. Don't phone and stack, peeps.

Comment: but i got the alert "[object Object]" no data came

Comment: <option *ngFor="let item of products" id={{item}} value={{item.PackingTypeID}}>{{item.PackingtypeName}}</option>
 like this .....

Comment: Don't forget to add the brackets around value, like: [value]="item". Because you want to perform object binding.

Comment: @SebastianMünster same  "[object Object]"

Comment: Try with the console log and check plz. As it might be json object you need to stringify if you want to see value on alert. In console log you will get to know.

Comment: That's the point, though - when JS attempts to print an object instead of a basic type, it will come out as "[object Object]" - that means you actually have a full object with properties to play with instead of a single, primitive value or worse, ``undefined``. In this case, in theory, your object is your actual product item, containing an ID (PackingTypeID) and name (PackingtypeName). Exactly what you want in one package.